# Using hyphenation to avoid ambiguity

Tags: hyphenation, academia

When I write a research paper, I often use hyphenation in order to avoid ambiguity. For example, consider the phrase

> fractionally Pareto optimal allocation

A person who does not know these terms may read the phrase in at least two ways: "**optimal allocation** that are **fractionally Pareto**" or "**allocations** that are **fractionally Pareto optimal**".

Since the second meaning is correct, I write

> fractionally-Pareto-optimal allocation

But, I am then criticized by the language editor for using too many hyphens.

Is it common to use hyphens in such a way in order to avoid ambiguity? If not, how else can I void ambiguity?

Comment: Try restructuring your sentences and paragraphs, and use different methods to convey the same information. Due to lack of context my examples can be inaccurate, but it's worth a try: "The allocations, who are fractionally Pareto optimal, ..." or "The allocations (fractionally Pareto optimal)...". Break up your sentences like the first option, or put the describing part in a parenthesis, as if it is something you're adding. The second option can falsely make something seem less important though, so beware.

Comment: Yes, it's tricky. Poor style or  confusability? The only way round this is to do as  @A. Kvåle suggests. Or get a different editor (who realises that clarity trumps aesthetics).

Comment: There should be no hyphen after *fractionally*. As an adverb that ends in *-ly*, all major style guides would advise against its hyphenation. In others words, it should just be *fractionally Pareto-optimal allocation*. I can't really imagine any editor who would be okay with a hyphen after that first word.

Comment: For whatever it’s worth, I use as many hyphens as possible in my academic writing (I wouldn’t put one after *fractionally*) and I never faced problems with this.